# Testing IPsec with Nagios / Icinga?

Tags: windows, monitoring, nagios, ipsec

Several of my Windows servers are running IPsec. There are a small handful that have problems when rebooting with the IPsec services not coming up.

As a result I'd like to set up a monitoring check that will verify that IPsec is working as it should. **I want these tests to be as complete as possible. Which option would give the most reliable results?**

I'm thinking any of the following options would work, but I'm not sure which is the most reliable detection method.

1. initiate an IPsec handshake (not sure how yet, maybe install the strongswan vpn client?)
2. verify ip protocol 50 / 51 availability
3. Verify UDP port 500 availability, e.g. `sudo nmap secure-casadev -sU -p 500 -Pn`

Comment: Have the Windows servers self-test ipsec (somehow?), and then submit the test results to Nagios?

Comment: Just a note: In every IPSec implementation I've worked with (Linux, Cisco, FreeBSD, OSX), the only way to "initiate an IPsec handshake" is to generate traffic that matches an SA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if the only foolproof way of testing this is to create an IPsec association between your Nagios server and each Windows Server, and perform some arbitrary check that can only succeed if the IPsec association is healthy.

Perhaps *all* of the checks from the Nagios host should require the IPsec tunnel to be up?

Comment: This is good advice. Be sure to use service dependencies so you don't get a dozen alerts when the IPsec tunnel goes down.